# These files came with my computer, in a different partition of my HDD. What do they do?

Tags: windows-8

I have the following files:

[image]

I know what the ones that are **not** surrounded by red do. What do the ones that are surrounded by red?

This came with my computer, and it looks like it's on a different partition of my drive.

Comment: And what's strange? Logical disk with drivers vendor?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what they do. I don't need the other ones so if they are useless I'm just going to give the space back over to my C:\ partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the contents of those directories it's difficult to tell, but likely they're device drivers or the utilities that come with your laptop.

The drivers are for:

- [AHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Host_Controller_Interface)
- The card reader
- The chipset

The *NoWifi* looks like it's an utility to disable the Wi-Fi, and the *EnergyManagement* probably are the power management tools.

Comment: Yes, but what are the drivers for?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @chipperyman573 What do you mean what are the drivers for? Do you not understand the term driver or do you not understand what AHCI, card reader, chipset etc are?